# Change a recursion function for a loop

Tags: python, loops, python-2.7, optimization, recursion

I have read, that recursion in python works very slowly. Is it possible to change this recursion into a loop function, which will work faster?
My function is a little bit complicated, but I will try to show most important parts:

```
class Element(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.priority = randint(1000)
    # some other operations and functions

import heapq

def fun(name):

      if condition():
         e = Element(name)
         # make some operations
         for i in e.sublist:
             if condition2():
                   heapq.heappush(heap,e)
             else:
                   updatepriority(e)
      if heap:
         top = heapq.heappop(heap)
         fun(top.name)
```

So I have a recursion function, which search throw many sublists and builds a priority queue using heapq module.
If I have a recursion function like for example counting Fibonnaci numbers I can easly transform recursion into loop. But in my function, I have no return statement, so I am not sure how I can do that.

Comment: `heap` is not defined before used in `if heap:`.

Comment: also `new Element(name)` is not how you initialize classes in python. Just use `Element(name)`.

Comment: _"recursion in python works very slowly"_ As far as I know, there is nothing inherently slow in using recursion with Python. This is the extra function call (being recursive or not) that slow down things compared to an inlined loop. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Python does not have tail-call optimisation, Therefore the stack will grow so you can get a stackoverflow, or out of memory. The stack manipulation will cause it to be a **little** slower than a loop.

Comment: @AndrewJohnson Yes, because it is defined in other function, which is not here, so I didn't wrote about that. But I think everyone knows that `heap` just a list.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this fairly directly, actually. Just initialize the heap with your root first, then you can iterate using `while`.

```
def fun(root):
  # Initialize the heap with your root element.
  heap = []
  if condition():
    e = Element(root)
    # make some operations
    for i in e.sublist:
      if condition2():
        heapq.heappush(heap,e)
      else:
        updatepriority(e)

  # Now we can iterate through the remainder of the heap.
  while heap:
    top = heapq.heappop(heap)
    if condition():
      e = Element(top.name)
      # make some operations
      for i in e.sublist:
        if condition2():
          heapq.heappush(heap,e)
        else:
          updatepriority(e)
```

If you pass an actual heap element into the function parameter, instead of the `name`, then you can immediately push it into the `heap` and skip that initial step, making your code simpler.

```
def fun(root):
  heap = [root]

  # Now we can iterate through the remainder of the heap.
  while heap:
    top = heapq.heappop(heap)
    if condition():
      e = Element(top.name)
      # make some operations
      for i in e.sublist:
        if condition2():
          heapq.heappush(heap,e)
        else:
          updatepriority(e)
```

Comment: `[] is not [] == True`

Comment: Just use `while heap`.

Comment: @kroolik I knew it was in the original question and I'm not sure why I didn't just stick with it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can always convert recursion into iteration:

- First make sure that all recursive-calls are tail-calls, as you have done.

  ```
  def fun(name):

    if condition():
       e = new Element(name)
       # make some operations
       for i in e.sublist:
           if condition2():
                 heapq.heappush(heap,e)
           else:
                 updatepriority(e)
    if heap:
       top = heapq.heappop(heap)
       fun(top.name)
  ```
- Then make the tail-call have its own conditional, `if heap:` will appear twice in code.

  ```
  def fun(name):

    if condition():
       e = new Element(name)
       # make some operations
       for i in e.sublist:
           if condition2():
                 heapq.heappush(heap,e)
           else:
                 updatepriority(e)
    if heap:
       top = heapq.heappop(heap)
    if heap:
       fun(top.name)
  ```
- Now wrap in `do … while`, removing the tail call and putting the conditional predicate in the while, and handle the arguments to the recursion.

  ```
  def fun(name):
    do #not python

       if condition():
           e = new Element(name)
           # make some operations
           for i in e.sublist:
               if condition2():
                   heapq.heappush(heap,e)
               else:
                   updatepriority(e)
        if heap:
           top = heapq.heappop(heap)

        name = top.name
    while heap # not python
  ```
- Now convert to a while (python does not have do…while)

  ```
  def fun(name):
      heap=True
      while heap:

          if condition():
              e = new Element(name)
              # make some operations
              for i in e.sublist:
                  if condition2():
                      heapq.heappush(heap,e)
                  else:
                      updatepriority(e)
          if heap:
              top = heapq.heappop(heap)

          name = top.name
  ```

Note: creation of top does not need to be conditional.
Note: I did not fix any of your bugs

Comment: What happens if you use `heapq.heappush(heap,e)` and you've already assigned `heap` to be a boolean?

Comment: Simila to what happens when you use it before defining it. See note (I did not fix original bugs).